# highcharts animation multiple charts

Tags: highcharts

Hi I am going to have a lot of charts on a page, all build on highcharts js. But I want the animation of the chart to begin when I reach a section on the page.

I have set up some testing, but I can only make one chart animate. Why does chart number 2 not animate ?

```
<div class="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div class="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

$(function () {
var test = 
    [
        {
            name: 'Firefox',   
            y: 45.0
        },
        {
            name: 'IE',       
            y: 26.8
        },
        {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 12.8,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true
        },
        {
            name: 'Safari',    
            y: 8.5
        },
        {
            name: 'Opera',     
            y: 6.2
        },
        {
            name: 'Others',   
            y: 0.7
        }
    ];

$('.container').each(function() {

    $(this).highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: <br /> {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: test,
            animation : false
        }]
    });
})


var chart = $('.container').highcharts(),
        s = chart.series,
        sLen = s.length;

setTimeout(function() {    
    for(var i =0; i < sLen; i++){
        s[i].update({
            animation: true   
        }, false);   
    }
    chart.redraw();
}, 1000);
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/RtxvB/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's caused by using `$(".container").highcharts()` which return only first chart. Instead create for example array of charts, where will be stored, then you have simple access to them. See: http://jsfiddle.net/RtxvB/1/

```
var test = [{
    name: 'Firefox',
    y: 45.0
}, {
    name: 'IE',
    y: 26.8
}, {
    name: 'Chrome',
    y: 12.8,
    sliced: true,
    selected: true
}, {
    name: 'Safari',
    y: 8.5
}, {
    name: 'Opera',
    y: 6.2
}, {
    name: 'Others',
    y: 0.7
}];


var charts = []
$('.container').each(function () {

    charts.push(new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: this
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: test,
            animation: false
        }]
    }));
})

$(charts).each(function (ind, chart) {
    var s = chart.series,
        sLen = s.length;
    setTimeout(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < sLen; i++) {
            s[i].update({
                animation: true
            }, false);
        }
        chart.redraw();
    }, 1000);
});
```